# Why do ROS enviroment break after conda?

Tags: python, linux, docker, conda, ros

I am trying to use Contact-GraspNet in a Docker environment with a base image with pre-installed ROS. There are no issues with my image and I have used it for other purposes for ROS before. The issue is the recommended way of running Contact-Graspnet is through creating the conda enviroment and when I do that my packages don't build anymore and rospy doesn't work. I thought because ros is installed through apt it shouldn't be a problem? Here is the docker image i am using:

```
... 
general setup of the docker image
...

ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget

RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_23.3.1-0-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-py38_23.3.1-0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b

RUN echo "source activate contact_graspnet_env" >> ~/.bashrc \
    && /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"

RUN conda --version

WORKDIR /ros-ws

RUN cd src && \
    git clone https://github.com/NVlabs/contact_graspnet.git

RUN cd src/contact_graspnet && conda env create -f contact_graspnet_env.yml

RUN sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev -y

RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate contact_graspnet_env"

CMD bash
```

I tried doing a local installation of the conda packages but that didn't allow me to run contact-graspnet and I'm not sure about ROS.

Answer (score 0):

When you activate a `conda` environment, it prepends its own directories to the `PATH`. This can cause issues with `ROS`.

To fix that we could check that `ROS` setup scripts are sourced after you activate the `conda` environment, by adding the command to source the `ROS` setup script in your `.bashrc` after the line where you activate the conda environment, the `ROS` setup script must be something like `/opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`.